# ASP.NET Razor File Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, file-upload

I'm following this example on the MS website for File Uploads using Razor and C#.

If I have more than one File upload buttons, how would the C# code know which button the uploaded file is from? Based on the button the file was uploaded from, I will be saving files to specific folders.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/working-with-files

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
    @{
        var fileName = "";
        if (IsPost) {
            var fileSavePath = "";
            var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
            fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles/" +
              fileName);
            uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
        }
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>FileUpload - Single-File Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>FileUpload - Single-File Example</h1>
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(
            initialNumberOfFiles:1,
            allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
            includeFormTag:true,
            uploadText:"Upload")
        @if (IsPost) {
            <span>File uploaded!</span><br/>
        }
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to name the buttons the same, but give them different values.  You can then do a case statement and direct the logic based on the value.

Razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <input type="file" name="FirstUpload" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitID" id="submitID" value="Upload1" />

    <input type="file" name="SecondUpload" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitID" id="submitID" value="Upload2" />

}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
        {
            string btn = Request.Params["submitID"];

            switch (btn)
            {
                case "Upload1":

                    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var file = Request.Files[i];
                    }                      
                    break;

                case "Upload2":

                    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var file = Request.Files[i];
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up with following code:
**Razor**

```
//BeginForm and other staff
@foreach (var d in Model.Types)
{
    <input type="file" name="doc:@d.Id:upload" />//@d.Id is the key point
    <button formenctype="multipart/form-data"
      type="submit" formaction="/MyController/uploaddoc" 
      name="typeid" formmethod="post" value="@d.Id">//this way I send Id to controller
       Upload
    </button>
}
```

**MyController**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("mycontroller/uploaddoc")]//same as formaction
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadDoc(FormCollection data, int typeid)
{
    //restore inpput name
    var fl = Request.Files["doc:" + typeid.ToString() + ":upload"];
    if (fl != null && fl.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/app_data/docs");
        var fn = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();//random name
        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(path, fn)))
        {
            await fl.InputStream.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
    }

}
```